# Ruby on Rails: database all previous migration numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake, version

If I want to revert my db schema to a specific migration, I would need to know a specific version number. I checked

```
rake -T
```

but didn't find any one to list ALL previous db versions. I am using Rails 4.2.0, and the DB is not versioned using simple integers like 1, 2, ... but timestamp-like integers.

How may I get all the previousdb migration version numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure you do a preliminary research before you post a question in SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake db:migrate:status` will show all the migrations, along with whether they have been applied or not.

`

Comment: Sure. Not sure why I was voted down and minused my point.. could you vote it up please. LOL ;-D